# Documents that stop sending remote events when they are updated

Tags: sharepoint, event-handling, sharepoint-online, csom

I have a library in sharepoint online with a remote event receiver. It run ok.
Some properties of de documents are modified by  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client from a web aplication and them when de remote event is received another properties ara modified with the remote event receiver.
I have quite a few enviroments and all run fine except one. In this one, some documents are running ok but in some moment that I haven't detected yet, this documents stop sending remote event. They never send events again.Events are also not received if I modify the document directly in sharepoint.
The rest of the documents in the same library continues sending remote events.

I have tried deleting the events and re-registering them, but this does not solve the problem.
I would like to know if you know why it happens and how to fix it, or how to make the document able to send events again.

Thank you.